# How to remove or mask values in a numpy array based on another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays `xVal` and `yVal`. I also have a range for `xVal` say `(minVal,maxVal)`. I can get the values of `xVal` in the range using

```
xVal[(xVal>=minVal)&(xVal<=maxVal)]
```

or the index of values in `xVal` in range as

```
np.where((xVal>=minVal)&(xVal<=maxVal))
```

What is a pythonic approach to resize or mask `yVal` based on this range information of `xVal`, so I can plot `xVal` vs `yVal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the most pythonic answer I could come up with

Get the index of values not in range as

```
indexRemove = np.where(np.logical_not((xVal>=minVal)&(xVal<=maxVal)))
```

and then use `np.delete` to remove the index values from `xVal` and `yVal`

```
xVal2 = np.delete(xVal, indexRemove)
yVal2 = np.delete(yVal, indexRemove)
```